# How to download and apply kernel patches

Tags: kernel, patch

There are a number of websites sharing the same series of patches
I want to apply this series of patches https://lore.kernel.org/all/20190807155524.5112-1-steve.capper@arm.com/
What I would do is to copy past the patch and apply one by one but is that the only way? Is there another way to apply them ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Linux source code as a Git repository, you should be able to download the 'mbox' file of the entire list thread (look for "Thread overview: mbox.gz"), then feed it to the `git am` command which applies all patches as individual Git commits.

(You could preview the downloaded file using `mutt -f ~/Downloads/mbox`, e.g. to delete replies.)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question is are these patches custom?  If they are my idea won't help.

The best situation is if the patches are part of the kernel.  Then you just upgrade the whole kernel.  Hopefully you can use the package management of your OS to do this.

Otherwise, you will have download the kernel from kernel.org.  Then you will have to configure and compile it a far more complex and time consuming process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "recent" tool [b4](https://pypi.org/project/b4/).

[A quick introduction](https://people.kernel.org/monsieuricon/introducing-b4-and-patch-attestation).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).